# New Relic log when running elasticsearch daemon

Tags: elasticsearch, newrelic

I installed the New Relic java agent with elasticsearch (Not the elasticsearch new-relic plugin, mind you).

when running elasticsearch with either:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

or

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

It works fine, and the data flows to my dashboard.
However, whern running as a service, the logfile in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/newrelic/log` is not written to, so I cannot debug what is happening to new relic.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

But why do you need to see the NewRelic agent's log in the first place?  For what it's worth, you may want to be aware of http://sematext.com/spm/index.html